# Lag while scrolling

Tags: javascript, html, css, performance, scroll

When I scroll down the page, the whole browser is lagging. Only some browsers are lagging though, for example Google Chrome works perfectly on Windows 8.1 but is lagging on Mac.

I cannot pinpoint what could be causing the problem since it is showing a decent, over 30 frames per second on Google Chrome, and I cannot detect any big memory leaks or anything like that. Also, when I scroll really quick, there are grey/white squares.

I tried removing CSS properties which could be reducing FPS such as translate() or gray filter but none of that helps. The website is http://bredymer.dk/biler.aspx ( no www ).

Answer (score 2):

As I can't reproduce it I would suggest you start the other way round. Build up a copy of the page from scratch, adding blocks of elements one by one and observing whether the bottle neck is caused by the cheer number of elements, or a specific block. The first case is a bit hard to solve, as you have to structurally re-design the site, in the second case you will have to look into that block what specifically causes it. Either way, my guess is that all those `position: absolute`s can't be really healthy for the performance. Floating them would be a far cleaner solution, though harder to program with the expanding boxes.

Comment: The problem appears due to large amounts of items. On home page for example, I am also showing elements in exactly the same fashion but there are only 9 of them and the scroll works just fine. I think you might be right with absolute positioning, I will have to try that out and see how that works.

Comment: @KarolisRamanauskas: Depending on backward compatibility you can also look into the flexible box model. It makes it far easier to program what you want, but isn't as supported: http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox.

Comment: Thanks, that looks great, however does not meet browser requirements just yet. In a year I would probably use that, very exciting!